# Cocoa Changing properties of NSTextView

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSTextView object in my window.
I have 2 problems that I need to solve.

1) My NSTextView content changes between different NSStrings that I have set. I would like to make the text a bit bigger but when the app initialize, there will be no content there.How do I set it that all the Strings passed to it can make their size bigger. Thanks

2) I don't want my content editable by the user but when I uncheck "Editable" in the inspector, I wouldn't be able to change the content of the NSTextView myself in the code. How do I make it so that the content may change but the content remains unediable by the user? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instances of `NSAttributedString` to set the content of your text view. You can set up attributed strings so that they use a particular font size. When you do this, do it in your app controller's `-awakeFromNib` method to address the issue of there being no content when your application starts up.

You can still change the content of your text view, even if you reset the "Editable" flag. That only prohibits your users from changing the content. Have you actually *tried* changing the content programmatically?

**EDIT**

What follows is an example of using an attributed string. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/CreatingAttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000714-BBCCGGCC) on the subject covers it very nicely. If you're not using ARC, be sure to release `attrString` when you're done with it (or autorelease it).

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24.0];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"this is Helvetica at 24 points" attributes:attributes];

[[[self textView] textStorage] appendAttributedString:attrString];
```

Comment: I figured out how to change the content without the user changing but can you teach me how to clear all of the contents of the NSTextView?

Comment: Sure: `[yourTextView setString:@""];`

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand how to change the font size of the string. Can you give an example?

Comment: @user1927992 If my answer (and subsequent conversation) has been of help to you, don't forget to accept it. Thanks!